# Getting "java.lang.VerifyError: com/mashape/relocation/conn/ssl/AbstractVerifier" when trying to use unirest on android

Tags: java, android, ssl, unirest

I just added the unirest libraries to my android project and I'm trying to use a mashape api. But I'm getting this error. I think it has something to do with the https certificate but I'm not sure what to do.

```
        java.lang.VerifyError: com/mashape/relocation/conn/ssl/AbstractVerifier
        at com.mashape.relocation.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:124)
        at com.mashape.relocation.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getDefaultRegistry(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:98)
        at com.mashape.relocation.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:105)
        at com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options.refresh(Options.java:47)
        at com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options.<clinit>(Options.java:34)
        at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.prepareRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:153)
        at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:133)
        at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
        at com.example.fionn.deathwatch.MainActivity.showDate(MainActivity.java:113)
        at com.example.fionn.deathwatch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2181)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2276)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And my code I'm trying to run is...

```
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post("https://life-left.p.mashape.com/time-left")
                .header("X-Mashape-Key", "1NZITOdDGqmshKRAEdDbX0tp0WV2p1RR5SSjsnQYQIVwrANkhC")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .field("birth", "22 April 1977")
                .field("gender", "female")
                .asJson();
```